# create enum using other property name's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.7

how can I create enum class that its property use the value from other member? Like my following code

```
from enum import Enum
class ProjectPath(Enum):
    home = '~/home'
    app = '~/home/app'
    prefix = '~/home/app/prefix'
    postfix = '~/home/app/postfix'

'''
try to do something like
from enum import Enum
class ProjectPath(Enum):
    home = '~/home'
    app = f'{self.home.value}/app'
    prefix = f'{self.app.value}/prefix'
    postfix = f'{self.app.value}/postfix'
'''
```

Comment: just get rid of the self parts, the variable home is defined. there is no variable called self. so remove all the references to self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont try to refer to the variables inside as an enum, just uses them like local variables.

```py
from enum import Enum


class ProjectPath(Enum):
    home = '~/home'
    app = f'{home}/app'
    prefix = f'{app}/prefix'
    postfix = f'{app}/postfix'


print(*[f"{var=}" for var in ProjectPath], sep="\n")
```

**Output**

```
var=<ProjectPath.home: '~/home'>
var=<ProjectPath.app: '~/home/app'>
var=<ProjectPath.prefix: '~/home/app/prefix'>
var=<ProjectPath.postfix: '~/home/app/postfix'>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use:

```py
class ProjectPath(Enum):
    home = '~/home'
    app = f'{home}/app'
    prefix = f'{app}/prefix'
    postfix = f'{app}/postfix'
```